# Rails 3 multiple keywords filtering query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, algorithm, search

I am writing a filtering algorithm that takes the user input as array of keywords, like

```
@keywords = ['news', 'TV show', 'games', 'IT']
```

and to query the table, for example, videos table in my database. There's a string field in the table which includes a couple of tags delimited by comma. For a video instance, if its tags field includes one(or more) of the keywords, it should be returned. I started with something like

```
@videos = []
@keywords.each |word| do
  @videos.push(Video.where('tags LIKE ?', '%#{word}%'))
end
@videos = @videos.flatten
```

Then I found, first, it'll include duplicated videos, and second, it queries the database as many times as the length of the keywords which is not efficient at all.

Any suggestions to improve this?

Answer (score 0):

This would do it if you need the `like` clause:

```
@videos = Video.where( (@keywords.map { |kw| "tags like \'%#{kw}%\'" }).join(" or ") )
```

Probably not the most Ruby-esque, but straight forward.